Multivariate integral of the Dirac delta distribution $\int_\mathbb{S}\int_\mathbb{S}f(x,y)\delta(x-y-a)dxdy$
I am confused about the multivariate integral of the Dirac delta distribution $\int_\mathbb{S}\int_\mathbb{S}f(x,y)\delta(x-y-a)dxdy$, where $\mathbb{S}\subset\mathbb{R}^2$ is a unit circle. For any $a\in\mathbb{R^2}$ in the disc $B(0,2)\subset\mathbb{R}^2$, should it be $\int_\mathbb{S}f(y+a,y)dy$ or $\int_{\mathbb{S}\cap\{y: y+a\in\mathbb{S}\}}f(y+a,y)dy$? Is the latter zero?
There are two pairs of root of $x-y-a$, say $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$. Should the original integral be $f(x_1,y_1)+f(x_2,y_2)$?

Please explain your notation.  What does $\mathbb{S}$ denote?  You wrote that $a\in B(0,2)$.

$\mathbb{S}$ is a unit circle in $\mathbb{R}^2$ here

The expression can be rewritten as
$$
\int_\mathbb{S} \left(\int_{\mathbb{R}^d} 1_{\mathbb{S}}(x) f(x,y) \delta(x-y-a) dx \right) dy
$$
where $1_\mathbb{S}$ is the indicator function of the set $\mathbb{S}$ and $d$ is the dimension of the ball. So you get
$$
\int_\mathbb{S}  1_{\mathbb{S}}(y+a) f(y+a,y)  dy
$$
That is the second formula you have written. This is true regardless of what $\mathbb{S}$ is (but it has to be $d$ dimensional for the expression to make sense.)
Assuming $\mathbb{S}=\{ x \in \mathbb{R}^d : \|x\|=1\}$  : The set $\{y : y+a \in \mathbb{S}\}$ can be rewritten as the level set $\{y : \|a\|^2+2 a \cdot y=0\}$ that is a $d-1$-manifold and so it has  $d$-Lebesgue measure zero and so the integral is zero (if $a \ne 0$).
I don't get the last question. There are infinite many roots of $x-y-a$, namely $x=y+a$

Thank you for you answer. If $d=2$, let $\mathbb{S}$ be the unit circle, I think there are only two roots since both $x$ and $y$ must lie on the circle.

@ShuXiao for $x-y-a$ to be well defined you need $x,y$ to be 2 dimensional i.e. the equation becomes $(x_1,x_2)-(y_1,y_2)-(a_1,a_2)$ it has infinitely many solutions e.g. take $a=0$, then the solution are $(x,x)$ for any $x \in \mathbb{S}$

Thank you for you answer. If $d=2$, let $\mathbb{S}$ be the unit circle, I think there are only two roots since both $x$ and $y$ must lie on the circle. I read that $\delta(g(x))=\sum_i\frac{\delta(x-x_i)}{|g'(x_i)|}$, where ${x_i}$ are all the roots of $g$, on Wikipedia. So I am wondering if we can treat (x,y) in the original integral as a single higher-dimensional variable, and whether the integral is non-zero and related to those two roots.

Sorry, I guess I am still confused about it. Would you mind give me more hints about why there are infinitely many solutions?

What about when $a\neq0$?

@ShuXiao consider the 1-D case $x-y-a=0$ is a line for any value of $a$. A line has infinitely many points. In two dimensions $x-y-a=(x_1-y_1-a_1, x_2-y_2-a_2)=(0,0)$ each component has infinite many solutions. You can't consider (x,y) as an higher dimensional variable. The dimension does not match in that case

but $(x_1,x_2)$ and $(y_1,y_2)$ have to be on the unit circle, right?

@ShuXiao not really. As $a \in B(0,2)$ $\delta$ need to belong to $\mathcal{D}'(\mathbb{R}^2)$ that means that the integral is performed over $\mathbb{R}^2$ and so $x,y\in \mathbb{R}^2$. After that you multiply for the indicator function of $\mathbb{S}$ and so the integral became over $\mathbb{S}$.

I see. Thank you so much!
